# YASMIN CPU simulator instruction set, RISC-based but what does #h mean?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, risc

I'm working through a set of problems related to the YASMIN CPU/OS simulator with a RISC-like instruction set.  (Editor's note, possibly [this one](https://teach-sim.com/) or another version of it).   I just cant seem to find the answer to the following:

5. Add the following code and run:

```
STB #h41, 16
LDB 16, R03
ADD #1, R03
STB R03, 17
```

What is the significance of `h` in `h41` above?

There seems to be no information anywhere to reference. I have tried pairing different numbers with h to distinguish a pattern but to no avail. See my attempt below.

[image: CPU simulator attempt]

Comment: You can verify with an instruction manual: I think it means hex.

Comment: You can check if `h` means hex by using it with an add-immediate or mov-immediate to put a value into a register, then look in the debugger window to see the register value.  Also, googling on "YASMIN cpu simulator" found some links, including one I added to the question.  https://teach-sim.com/cpu-2/ has links to an instruction-set PDF for the ISA the simulator uses, which hopefully explains the asm syntax as well as the machine-code format.

Answer (score 1):

#h41 means literal value hex 41. h prefix simply means the following number is a hex number. As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

refer to [their tutorial (Investigating Programming Model 2)](https://teachsim.files.wordpress.com/2021/07/programming-model-2-tutorial.pdf) , where they gave an example on page **5** where they said :

> MSF
>
> PSH #h60 -> puts the number hex 60 on top of the stack
>
> CAL $Label2
>
> HLT

that means that `h` is indication that this number in **HEX** format and `#` means that it's a immediate value, so in the example you provided :

```
STB #h41, 16
```

`#h41` is a **HEX** number which is equivalent to **65** in decimal number systems.